# Disable pointer ghost trails on Windows

Tags: windows, mouse

I would like to turn off this ugly mess whereby whenever you move the mouse at any speed other than a crawl, the mouse pointer leaves ghost trails at regular intervals. It happens everywhere in Windows and also in some games. I suspect Windows is not reporting all mouse movement. It happens on a regular system OR my quad i5 3470 on 144HZ monitor with 1000hz mouse polling rate 1600 DPI, with MarkC mousefix or whatnot. I have gtx770 GPU with all devices' and OS throttling disabled, i.e. max performance at all times. What causes this and can I get rid of this?

Comment: Is this ghost trails visible to you on other computers?

Comment: if it's not actually 'mouse trails' in the Ease of Access control panel, then it's simply that your monitor's refresh is nowhere near as fast as you thought it was. One of my screens does that, the other doesn't, on the same settings.

Answer (score 3):

Open your start menu and type `mouse` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Check the following options, untick if necessary:

[image: Mouse Properties]

Comment: as i said, mouse pointer trails is OFF. This is not as heavy as this pointer trails, yet readily visible, just move your mouse repeatedly left and right. It's ghosting at intervals.

Comment: You didn't actually mention that Pointer Trails is off. But I suspect you are simply seeing what everyone sees when they move the mouse.

Comment: Try this: put your hand in front of a blank lightly coloured wall. Move your hand side to side, do you see a ghost hand? That's the [Vestibulo–ocular reflex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestibulo%E2%80%93ocular_reflex) failing to pursue a moving object correctly while the eyes are stationary.

Comment: didn't have this artifact on 85hz crt way back in windows xp days. Any other clues. I'm sure everyone can see it and that it can be ascribed to particular hardware/software/config. On my home system i can run pixperan test and see that such regular interval ghosting does not happen to small moving objects on screen. It only happens with mouse pointer.

Comment: @chriswww You can't rely on your eyes for this. If you want to be certain, get a camera, set it to a shutter speed of 1/60 (if your monitor is 60 Hz refresh) and take a photo while moving the mouse over a black background. I just did a similar test and it shows just the one cursor, with a second faded one occasionally (I suspect due to the camera catching the refresh). Of course, it looks like a ghost trail with your eyes, due to the effect Michael mentioned, but as far as the computer hardware and software are concerned there's only one.

Comment: There *is* the possibility that some particulars of your setup cause actual ghosting. But you need to do an objective test (with a camera, not your eyes) to prove that.